# Beginner C++ - do some simple calculations

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

So I'm trying to do some simple math calculations, but I can't even put a number in a variable.

```
int choice;
cout << "\nEnter your choice..." << endl;
cin >> choice;

if (choice == 1) {
    cout << "All entries:" << endl;

    sqlite::sqlite db( "student_marks.sqlite" ); 
    auto cur = db.get_statement();         
    cur->set_sql( "SELECT * FROM marks;" );
    cur->prepare(); 

    while( cur->step() )  {
        int apples = cur->get_text(2);
        int cherries = cur->get_text(3);
        int sumFruits = apples + cherries
    }
}
```

Gives me the error

```
error: no viable conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to 'int'
```

How can I solve this problem?  If I do

```
cout << "Bananas number : " << cur->get_text(3) << endl;
```

it prints the value without any issues..

Thanks

Comment: read the error message.

Comment: `int apples = cur->get_text(2);` well what did you expect to happen?

Comment: so I need to convert `cur->get_text(0)` to an int?

Comment: That wasn't very helpful guys. Reading the error message won't help him much if he doesn't know how to fix it. It is a straight forward question. Either post an answer or don't, but there's no need to be condescending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert a `std::string` to an int - try using [`stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
int apples = std::stoi(cur->get_text(2));
int cherries = std::stoi(cur->get_text(3));
```

Comment: If I do this I get the error `no viable conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to 'int'`

Comment: Did you do it both for `apples` and `cherries`? Oh, my.

Comment: Then maybe look where the error happens and fix it?? It's the same error...